# Angle of $x$ dependant on a kite in a rhombus

Tags: geometry, contest-math

[image]

$ABCD$ is a rhombus. $E$ is the midpoint of $BC$. If $BAE = x$, then $FECG$ is a kite if $x$ is equal to what?

Can someone please help me with this question? I just want a hint to help me because I am struggling to proceed. I know $AGB = 90$ degrees. and $CG = EC$ and $FE=FG$. Please provide me with a hint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT:** If $FECG$ is a kite,then the $\angle FEC=90^\circ$, and $EC=GC$. This makes the triangle $\Delta ABC$ equilateral. Can you take it from here?

Comment: I proceeded to some extent. Am I correct in saying that $AE$ bisects angle $BAC$? If so, how?

Comment: @AspiringMathlete Yes. $\Delta AEB \cong \Delta AEC$ by RHS congruency.

Comment: Thank you. I got it congruent by SSS congruency. So $x = 30$ if I am not mistaken?

Comment: @AspiringMathlete yes.